# using SQLiteDataBase to get constant values

Tags: android, sqlite

In an SQlite editor, I can execute the query:

```
SELECT `rowid`, `start_nr`, `zeit4`, `true` FROM ergebnisse UNION SELECT rowid, start_nr, zeit4, false FROM result_not_assigned ORDER BY zeit4;
```

For column 4, I got the value 'true' or 'false' depending on the table.

Android `SQLiteDataBase` `rawQuery` gives me back:

> no such column: 0 (code1)

How can I avoid the error?

Comment: sqlite doesn't support boolean values. Use an integer 0 or 1 for saving boolean

Comment: can you using true or false as column name

Comment: Oh sorry, with 1 or 0 i got the same result

Comment: can you show the code you are using for the rawQuery and also the full message which should say what column cannot be found. Also it could be that SQL is fine but the table doesn't actually have the column. So perhaps also detail how you create the table.